# PMSM motor - full-speed shorting over low-side FETs

Tags: mosfet, motor

I have an application with a PMSM, that should stop the motor as fast as possible when an error is detected in the controller (assume the current cannot be controlled anymore with FOC).

The motor drives a load that has the same intertia as the motor itself. The easiest way to stop as fast as possible is to short the low-side MOSFETs but I'm unsure if this might damage the MOSFETs.

**Motor:**

[image]

**MOSFETs (NTMFS10N3D2C):**

https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ntmfs10n3d2c-d.pdf

[image]

When we assume the rated speed of 3000rpm and the motor is fully shorted, current rise is limited by the inductance and the total current by the internal resistance of the MOSFETs and the motor. When we assume the current can rise to the maximum current of (48 V/(0.066 Ω + 9 mΩ) = 640 A) and a VDS of 9 mΩ · 640 A = 5.76 V, the SOA gives a maximum of 100 A for 1 ms and that might be way too low.

So, do you think this will fry the MOSFETs or might the motor go into saturation and the current won't rise that high?

Comment: What does 9mΩ come from? I see this figure at Vgs(on) = 6V, surely you'd want to drive it as hard as possible, for such a heavy load?

Comment: Also, grenading the motor / attached load / controller just because of a control glitch? That sounds awfully dangerous for most applications. I doubt that a semiconductor solution would be acceptable in such case anyway; how about slamming down a contactor instead?  Possibly a normally-closed one so it's also safe in event of power loss.  (If the contacts weld, that's not a bug it's a feature, it's anti-restart prevention?...heh.)

Answer (score 0):

The energy from the stated inertia is 1/2*(inertia) * (angular velocity squared).  Your angular velocity is 3,000 RPM or 314 radians/sec, so your energy from inertia is 9 joules.  The energy in the inductor (worst case) is 1/2*(inductance)*(current squared).  In this case the inductance energy adds only 29 millijoules.  Add them together to get the total energy that your MOSFET must absorb, then divide by .001 to determine the average power absorption during your one millisecond braking period (about 9,000 watts), or about nine times the motor rated power.  Since your motor magnetics must do the braking, you won't get enough stopping torque from the motor to stop in this time period.  The best you can do is about three times, since your peak torque is three times your motor rated torque.

Stopping with a value three times the motor torque will probably not hurt your driver since it is such a short duration (if you don't do it too often).

Good luck!

Comment: The peak torque is 3 times the nominal torque, but this does not mean that the motor will only pick up three times the nominal current, right? As I calculated above, there can flow way more current when looking at the internal resistance of the system, when there wont be any saturation in producing this current

Comment: When you are braking, the motor becomes a generator, saturation of the core still occurs,  and the torque coefficient still applies.  Peak torque is all you can get for stopping, and you can calculate the maximum current at peak torque using the torque coefficient.  This peak torque decelerates the rotor, and the generator current is the peak torque divided by the torque coefficient.

Comment: Hi John, yes that makes sense, but the saturation current can be much higher like in a transformer, right? At least from a Test I made with a smaller motor rated for 8.5A and peak of 20A I can easly reach up to 50A.

Comment: You are right, but in that case you are supplying current from an power source.  The current from braking (your generator) must come from the change in magnetic field from your motor magnets, which won't oversaturate your laminations.